# How to unselect last checked item from checkedListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to disable multiselection in CheckedListBox. I tried

```
checkedListBoxWersje.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One
```

but I still can check multiple items. So I want to unselect last checked item. Is it possible?

Comment: If you can select only a single button, shouldn't you use radio buttons?

Comment: @xanatos exactly my thought.

Comment: but there's no such thing as RadioButtonListBox.

Comment: The `SelectionMode` is something different, it determines how many items can be selected at once. For other list types controls, selection is indicated by a blue background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works.

```
if(e.NewValue.Equals(CheckState.Checked))
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
        if (i != e.Index)
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a GroupBox with RadioButtons?

If you really want to go with a CheckedListBox consider the following which allows only one item checked at a time.

```
namespace CheckListBoxSimple_C_Sharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
        }
        private const int maxNumberOfCheckedItems = 1; 
        void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckedListBox items = (CheckedListBox)sender;
            if (items.CheckedItems.Count > (maxNumberOfCheckedItems - 1))
            {
                e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }            
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo" });

            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, false);
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(3, false);
        }
    }
}
```